# MVC: One Model, Two Views - Passing Parent to Child

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model

I am having a problem creating a Model across two Views. I have not been able to find a example of this although I suspect part of the reason is not knowing how to phrase the question well. Please see below for a description of what I am trying to do.

I have a Model called a Referral which has a many-to-one relationship with a Model called Visitor (a Visitor can make multiple Referrals). When the user navigates to the Referral section of the web page, they should be prompted to first fill out the form for the Visitor info. Once the Visitor info has been filled out, the user should be taken to a new form (new View) where they fill out the Referral info. Since a portion of the Referral info is the Visitor info, I need to pass one to the other.

The way I've gone about this is to have two separate Views, one for getting Visitor info and one for getting Referral info. Each has a Get and a Post with the Post for Visitor returning a RedirectToAction with the name of the Referral View and a Referral object with the Visitor info populated:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateVisitor(Visitor visitor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var visitorExists = db.Visitors.Any(v => v.FirstName == visitor.FirstName && v.LastName == visitor.LastName);
            if (visitorExists == false)
            {
                db.Visitors.Add(visitor);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            Referral referral = new Referral();
            referral.Visitor = visitor;

            return RedirectToAction("CreateReferral", referral);
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

The idea is to pass this info to the next (Referral) form so that the Visitor portion is filled out and all that's left to do is enter the Referral info. I tried passing the partially created view the Get but then the Post began to complain that there was another method taking in the same model.

```
    //GET: Referrals/CreateReferral
    public ActionResult CreateReferral(Referral referral)
    {
        return View(referral);
    }
```

Is there a way to pass this information that won't cause the Post method to complain? Maybe via a Visitor ID that I can use in the Get method to create the referral?

Any input is greatly appreciated. I've been trying to figure it out myself but haven't been able to find relevant info online and am worried about going too far down the wrong path.

Hope to hear from you,

Yusif Nurizade

Comment: You cannot pass a complex object containing properties which are complex objects using `RedirectToAction()` (look at the url its generating for the `Visitor` property to understand). You have already saved the `Visitor` so just pass its `ID` to the `CreateReferral()` GET method

Comment: But why not just do it all in one method/view?

Comment: You can create session object for Referral and access in CreateReferral. And after use you can destroy session. After creating this just do return RedirectToAction("CreateReferral")

Comment: Stephen thanks for your suggestion, I tried it and had good results. I want to check the answer as resolved but all I have by my question is the star. Maybe because you edited? Thanks again!